# Why did the value of "fileInputStream.read()" be changed?

Tags: java, io, myeclipse

I think that only the value of i was changed, but why it was fileInputStream.read()?

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileStream_byte1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileOutputStream fOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("FileStream_byte1.txt");
    fOutputStream.write(-1);
    fOutputStream.close();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("FileStream_byte1.txt");
    int i;

    System.out.println("  " + fileInputStream.read());
    fileInputStream.close();
}
}
```

//The result is 255

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileStream_byte1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    FileOutputStream fOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("FileStream_byte1.txt");
    fOutputStream.write(-1);
    fOutputStream.close();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("FileStream_byte1.txt");
    int i ;
    while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1)
        System.out.println("  " + fileInputStream.read());
    fileInputStream.close();
}
}
```

//The result is -1

Comment: Should there be a `while` loop in the first snippet similar to the second snippet? Do you have other text in your file before you write/read from it?

Comment: I don't know, but the point I want to know is "i = fileInputStream.read()" only changed the value of i, did not it? The same point is they all print ("  " + fileInputStream.read())

Comment: Are you only wondering why `-1` is the result of your second example? Or are you also wondering why `255` is the result of the first example even though you wrote `-1` to the file?

Comment: Did the while loop change the value of read() every time? I thought tthe value of read() is a constant.

Comment: Do any of the answers below answer your question.  if so please consider to upvote and/or accept

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you read `255` (in first case) despite writing `-1` can be seen in the documentation of [`OutputStream.write(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(int)) (**emphasis** mine):

> Writes the specified byte to this output stream. The general contract for `write` is that one byte is written to the output stream. **The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument `b`. The 24 high-order bits of `b` are ignored.**

[`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) gives no indication of changing that behavior.

Basically, `InputStream.read` and `OutputStream.write(int)` use `int`s to allow the use of *unsigned* "bytes". They both expect the `int` to be in the range of `0`-`255` (the range of a byte). So while you called `write(-1)` it will only write the "eight low-order bits" of `-1` which results in writing `255` to the file.

---

The reason you get `-1` in the second case is because you are calling `read` twice but there is only one byte in the file and you print the result of the second read.

From the documentation of [`InputStream.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) (**emphasis** mine):

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an `int` in the range `0` to `255`. **If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value `-1` is returned.** This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can find that out by reading the documentation, quoting

"

> public int read() throws IOException. It reads a byte of data from this input stream. This method blocks if no input is yet available. Specified by:
>   read in class InputStream. **Returns: the next byte of data, or -1 if the
>   end of the file is reached.** Throws: IOException - if an I/O error
>   occurs.

"

It returns -1 because it reaches the end of the file.
In your while loop, it reads the byte of data you wrote, doesn't print anything and then the next time it tries to read a byte of data, there is none, so it returns -1 and since its matching your condition it prints it proceeding to exit the subroutine

Comment: So, every time the while loop is performed, the value of read() was changed, until all the data of file have been read at the same time its value has been changed into -1?

Comment: The while loop executed only two times. First reading the bye of data of your written number so i=255, then trying to read, but finding nothing in the file thus i=-1.

The reason you wrote -1, but the program reads 255 is because it doesn't read numbers, it reads bytes of data, if you don't know the difference you can use the search to find more answers on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are calling `read` twice, the first time it will return `255` then the next time `-1` indicating that the stream is ended

try

```
while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1)
    System.out.println("  " + i);
```

Comment: The first time read() was 255, the second time it was -1, was not it? If -1 means the stream was ended, what does 255 means? I never input 255 into the file...

Comment: see the javadocs for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(int) and consider `Byte b = -1;
  System.out.println("" + (b & 0xFF));`